# Why is st_blocks always reported in 512-byte blocks?

Tags: stat, api

I was debugging a fuse filesystem that was reporting wrong sizes for `du`. It turned out that it was putting `st_size / st_blksize` [*] into `st_blocks` of the `stat` structure. The Linux manual page for `stat(2)` says:

```
struct stat {
    …
    off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
    blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
    blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
    …
};
```

What is `st_blksize` for if `st_blocks` is in 512B blocks anyway?

[*] which looks wrong anyway, as integer division doesn't account for the fractional part…

Comment: By historical reason. All UNIXes use block (512 bytes) instead of kilobyte because in the past the size of disk sector was 512 bytes

Comment: You should put `st_blocks = (st_size + 511) / 512` -- maybe needlessly obfuscating it through an obtuse macro like `ROUNDING_UP_DIV_BY_SECTORS()` so the 1st midwit that comes along is impressed by the professional looking code instead of start carping about magic numbers and things he doesn't understand;-)

Comment: @RomeoNinov

`In [4]: os.stat('/vmlinuz').st_blksize  Out[4]: 4096`

MAGIC!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`st_blocks` is [defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) as

> Number of blocks allocated for this object.

The size of a block is implementation-specific. On Linux it’s always 512 bytes, for historical reasons; in particular, it used to be the typical size of a disk sector.

`st_blksize` is unrelated; it’s

> A file system-specific preferred I/O block size
>                          for this object. In some file system types, this
>                          may vary from file to file.

It indicates the preferred size for I/O, *i.e.* the amount of data that should be transferred in one operation for optimal results (ignoring other layers in the I/O stack).

Comment: Ah, so they have a different purpose actually. That explains a lot. Thanks!